# Shape of passed values is (12, 1), indices imply (1, 12)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matrix

I tried to create a table.

```
p_data = ["20", "30", "40", "50", "60", "70", "80", "90",
          "100", "110", "120", "130"];
p_columns = ["2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017",
             "2018", "2019", "2020", "2021"]

data_frame = pd.DataFrame(columns=p_columns , index=["house"], data=p_data )
```

I got an error:
**Shape of passed values is (12, 1), indices imply (1, 12)**

I want my table looks like this:
[image of what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRKOf.png)

Someone can help me please?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask], and show the output you want as formatted text, [not as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551). Make sure to *ask a specific question*; "Someone can help me please?" [does not qualify](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236). Note well that this is **not a discussion forum**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `[data]` as the input must be 2D if you specify the index/columns:

```
data_frame = pd.DataFrame(columns=p_data, index="house", data=[p_data])
```

output:

```
       20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90  100  110  120  130
house  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90  100  110  120  130
```

Also I imagine you rather want `p_columns` as columns:

```
data_frame = pd.DataFrame(columns=p_columns, index="house", data=[p_data])
```

output:

```
      2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017 2018 2019 2020 2021
house   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90  100  110  120  130
```

Comment: Also thanks for the p_columns.
I did not notice it because I could not see the table because of the error 